# Displaying Missed Calls In Twilio Call log

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, twilio

I am implementing  voice  call feature using Twilio SDK in one of my application. I don't know how can I get the missed call logs in Twilio.

I am calling from my mobile to Twilio number. As soon as the client started ringing I have disconnected the call from my mobile and wanted to show that as Missed call in my call logs.

here the issue I am having is when I want to display the "missed call" it's not working. I see the call statuses but it seems like almost every call is being marked as "completed"
How can I get missed calls in Twilio call log

Please help if anyone had done this.

Answer (score 1):

When you `dile` add two parameters

```
'action'=>  "www:yourwebsite.com/your/url"
'method' => "GET"
```

This will submit a Get request to `"www:yourwebsite.com/your/url"`

```
 if ($request->DialCallStatus == 'no-answer')
 {
      Call status = "You Missed a call from" . $request->number;
 }
```